# Unterschied zwischen "erwarten" und "sich versprechen von"

Tags: synonym

In welchen Fällen benutzt man das Verb "*sich versprechen von etw.*" statt "*erwarten*" bzw. "*sich etw. erhoffen*". Zum Beispiel:

> In den nächsten Tagen erwartet man hohe Temperaturen

Passt hier das Verb sich versprechen von etw.

> In den nächsten Tagen *verspricht man sich von* hohen Temperaturen

Comment: Achtung, es ist "sich etwas von etwas versprechen". In deinem Beispiel kannst du "von" getrost streichen. (Und das finale N in hoch.)

Comment: @Em1 It should rather be *Von den nächsten Tagen verspricht man sich hohe Temperaturen*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Erwarten" means "to expect". It's a simple statement without implications on cause or effect.

> Wir erwarten mehr Umsatz.
>
> We expect more sales.

"Sich etwas von etwas anderem versprechen" involves planning: by doing something you expect a certain result.

> Von den niedrigen Preisen versprechen wir uns mehr Umsatz.
>
> We expect more sales because of the lower prices.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach die beste Antwort. Was ich vermisse: *sich versprechen von* impliziert einen persönlichen Nutzen. Bei den "hohen Temperaturen in den nächsten Tagen" sehe ich den nicht, wenn wir nicht gerade von einem sehr kalten Winter sprechen, oder eine Knappheit an Heizmaterial herrscht.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is quite wrong. The simple reason is that "Sich versprechen von" takes *two* complements, not one, with the approximate meaning

> Ich verspreche mir sonnige Tage vom Sommer.
>
> I *anticipate* summer *in the hope that it will bring* sunny days.

Your example has only one of these two, so it's simply ungrammatical, just as if you'd said *Ich verspreche.